# What ranks give you drops in CSGO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I really wanna know what ranks give you drops in CSGO

Answer (score 6):

**Skill Ranks**

You get drops on all ranks.

**Profile Levels**

You get drops on levelup, on every levelup, limited to once every week.

Comment: You should add this; you don't get drops every level up; only on a level up EVERY WEEK

Comment: @skully thanks, added. been some while I played CS so forgot some details.

Answer (score -3):

You get drops on every rank except if u ranked up that week but chance of getting any kind of drop like case if u ranked up that week is **REALLY** small!

Comment: Why  the heck did people downvote this it IS possible because you can get a drop like a case....